# How many ways are there to combine a three-character label consisting of a number and a letter?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

The digits can be repeated and should form a weakly increasing sequence, while the letters can appear in any order but can’t be repeated. For instance, 99F and 3W5 are valid. How many combinations are there in total?

Comment: The question in the title is not clear.  Must the sequence contain both letters and digits?

Comment: You should not have changed your question from four characters to three characters since that has the effect of invalidating the answer you already received.  You still have not made clear whether the sequence must contain both a letter and a digit.

Answer (score 1):

The ways to choose digits in a weakly increasing sequence is that same as the number of ways to choose them if order doesn't matter. This is because every unordered collection of digits (with repeats allowed) can be ordered in exactly one way to give a weakly increasing sequence.

The number of ways to choose (say) three digits with repeats allowed but order not important is given by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)): it is $\mathrm{C}^{10+3-1}_{3-1}$. So the number of ways with three digits is $\mathrm{C}^{10+3-1}_{3-1}\times 26\times 4$ (the last $4$ is the number of positions for the letter).

Comment: Thanks, I understand how it works now.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a three-combination with repetitions from $10$ digits, the formula is $\binom{10+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{12}2$, and *any* such choice can be arranged in a weakly increasing sequence in *just one way.*

But first put in **a** alphabets  in $\binom{3}{a}P(26,a) 
$ ways, (presumably only in capitals, as in your examples)

Then the weakly increasing numerals can be put in $\binom{12}{2-a}$ ways,
giving $\binom{3}{a}*P(26,a)*\binom{12}{2-a}$ combined ways

Sum up for $a = 0\; to\; 3$

$$\sum_{a=0}^3\binom{3}{a}P(26,a)\binom{12}{2-a}$$

Comment: idk from where I got it into my head that it is a $4$ digit code ! Corrected now, though I guess it might not have bothered you.

Comment: Oh, I see you revised it from a $4$ digit code to a $3$ digit one; I don't see the point, unnecessarily confuses. I thought I was in a haze, really unsettling.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Since I was just trying to get the concept right, I thought modifying it to three would make the topic easier to understand.

Comment: Anyway, what's done is done, and cannot be undone without making confusion worse confounded ! But pl strictly avoid in future !